# Are all statements in a stored procedure ONE transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, rollback

If a stored procedure contains multiple statements e.g. first an `insert`, then an `update` and finally a `delete`s and the stored procedure gets killed in the middle of the `delete`, does the `insert` and `update` also have to be rolled back? Or does it only roll back the `delete` i.e. the implicit transaction?

Comment: This https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46266/6548 gives a nice little demo of the fact that statements inside a stored proc are NOT within a single transaction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), each statement will be executed as an implicit transaction. If a statement fails then the effect of prior statements will remain committed.

Note that the entire stored procedure may be executed within an explicit transaction created by the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

insert and update have to be commited but delete Statement was rolled back

Answer (score 0):

since you have no explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION in the stored procedure, each statement will run on its own with no ability to rollback any changes if there is an error.

However, if before you call the stored procedure you issue a BEGIN TRANSACTION, then all statements are grouped within a transaction and can either be COMMITted or ROLLBACKed following stored procedure execution.

Reference: KM.
[How does SQL Server treat statements inside stored procedures with respect to transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622069/how-does-sql-server-treat-statements-inside-stored-procedures-with-respect-to-tr)